# How to open a new window in Google Gadget?

Tags: javascript, google-gadget, igoogle

It opens neither a tab nor a window: the code for a Google Gadget [here.](http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/113238372519026650011/test_open.xml) If you know 'target="_blank"' from HTML, I am looking for a similar tool for Google Gadgets. More precisely, I cannot understand why the JavaScript piece does not work:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: I might be overlooking, but what is the actual question?.. What element are you trying to add the target to?

Comment: Javascript is for web pages, not XML documents!

Comment: Josh: It is Googe Gadget where I have the script. Sorry for being confusing.

Comment: Ahem, @Masi: Don't you think you changed the whole meaning of the question?

Comment: @Masi @Boldewyn Thank you for drawing my attention here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want to open the new window, do it explicitly.

```
var query = "bijection";
var searchUrl = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";

if (query != "" && searchUrl != "") {
    searchUrl += escape(query);
    window.open(searchUrl); //You can pass additional parameters, look for window.open examples on the Internet.
    return false;
}
```

The target attribute is for link element () which instructs browser to open the URL in new window if user clicks on it.

Comment: What is then for this thing? Is it just open? But what is the parameter to open it in new tab?

Comment: Look at window.open examples here.

http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

And I don't think you can specify that new window should be opened in a tab.

Answer (score 2):

Open a new window with that target instead of replacing the current’s window URL:

```
var query = "bijection";
var searchUrl = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";
if (query != "" && searchUrl != "") {
    searchUrl += escape(query);
    var newWindow = window.open(searchUrl, '_blank');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It looks promising. How did you get it working? I tried: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/, Google Gadget editor and even the navbar in my browser. Anything does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
searchUrl += escape(query);
thenewwindow=window.open(searchUrl,'Google','height=600,width=450');
return false;
```